# R Putting Loop output in Matrix

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have the following problem.

I have a large matrix called cleantable7. Now I am running the following for loop:

```
´´´
for (row in 1:nrow(cleantable7))
{
codephon = phonetic(cleantable7[row,], method = c("soundex"), useBytes = FALSE)
codephon2 = codephon[!duplicated(codephon)]
print(codephon2)
}
´´´
```

Now I want all of the output generated from print(codephon2) to be filled in a matrix.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hello, please provide an example of your data that you would use this code on, along with your expected output.

Comment: From the `r` tag (hover or click): Please provide [minimal and reproducible example(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1422451) along with the desired output. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with `library()` calls.